# Upload de Arquivo em JSF com ajax

Tags: ajax, java-ee, jsf-2.2, spring-security

Estou tentando fazer upload de um arquivo qualquer qualquer pelo elemento **h:inputFile**  do próprio jsf, e, tento fazer isso com ajax, mas quando tento fazer o upload aparece esse erro no console do navegador...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined
    at Object.response (jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:2814)
    at Object.onComplete (jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:1779)
    at FrameTransport.AjaxEngine.req.xmlReq.onreadystatechange (jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:1760)
    at FrameTransport.callback (jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:367)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (jsf.js.xhtml?ln=javax.faces&stage=Development:400)
```

Estou usando a seguintes bibliotecas do jsf:

> jsf-impl.2.2.15
>
> jsf-api.2.2.15

Também estou utilizando spring security.

O código do página xhtml está desta forma:

```
            <h:inputFile value="#{imagemPerfil.arquivo}" required="true" >

            </h:inputFile>
            <h:commandButton 
                class="btn btn-primary" value="Salvar" action="#{imagemPerfil.handleFileUpload()}">

                <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />

            </h:commandButton>

        </h:form>
```

E do Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="imagemPerfil")
@SessionScoped
public class MudarImagemPerfil implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3131478679593318664L;
    private Part arquivo;

    public Part getArquivo() {
        return arquivo;
    }

    public void setArquivo(Part arquivo) {
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
    }


    public MudarImagemPerfil() {

    }

    public void handleFileUpload() {

        if(arquivo != null) {
            System.out.println("file size: " + arquivo.getSize());
            System.out.println("file type: " + arquivo.getContentType());
        }else {
            System.out.println("Arquivo está nulo");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Dê uma olhada neste artigo. Acho que irá ajudá-lo.

Segundo este artigo, existe um bug no Mojarra que faz com que seja necessário submeter a página inteira `render='@all'.`.

http://blog.triadworks.com.br/upload-de-arquivos-com-jsf-2-2

Comment: Na verdade não estou usando primefaces, o que estava no Bean foi somente um teste que realizei e esqueci de remover... estou utilizando jsf puro... no caso sua solução aplica-se somente ao primefaces, mas obrigado por tentar ajudar!